# How to set up rating table SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to figure out how to set up a database table that will handle rating of specific users. Every user is one "blog", I would like users to be able to vote other users.

```
Table users
id(primary) username password email
Table rating
value user_id(foreign key)
```

The problem is that I can't find out, how to make another user able to rate the other user, and store it in the rating table. I would like it to look something like:

user id 2 voted user id 3 with value 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should consider changing your tables to something like this:

```
Table users (id (primary key), username, password, email)
Table rating (rated_by_user (foreign key), rated_user (foreign key), rating)
```

Both foreign keys would refer to `users.id`.

then an insert statement like `insert into rating values (2, 3, 5);` would indicate that user id 2 rated user id 5 with rating value 5.

The rating table should probably have a primary key (rated_by_user, rated_user) too.

Comment: Perfect answer, thank you so much. Is there no need for primary key?

Comment: @Nanash Oh, that would depend on if you want to allow users to rate the same user more than once (which I guess you might not). There should probably be a composite primary key set on rating for (rated_by_user, rated_user). I just didn't include it.